# Modify sbt run-main to send jvm parameter to the launched program

Tags: sbt

I want to modify the sbt launch command:

```
sbt "run-main <my-class> <program args>"
```

to include sending an app key/value pair to the jvm parameters visible to the app

```
-Dsome.app.specific.key=some-value
```

What is the syntax for starting sbt run-main with that jvm parameter?

Note: I do not want to touch the build.sbt